# Upgraded PHP and not displaying PHP pages

Tags: php

I upgraded my PHP version so I can install some software on my Raspberry Pi.  I followed these instructions from Heidi's Lab:

In `/etc/apt/sources.list` change stretch to buster, which is the next-stable/testing repository.

Update System:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Remove previous PHP:

```
sudo apt-get remove '^php.*'
```

Install `PHP 7.1`:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-fpm php7.1-cli or sudo apt-get install php7.1
```

However, when I now visit a PHP page in my browser I can just see the PHP rather than the code being run.  As you can probably tell, I'm a Linux novice and I'm fumbling my way through this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

---

When I run `php -v` I get:

```
PHP 7.1.20-1+b2 (cli) (built: Aug  3 2018 03:45:34) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.20-1+b2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Your problem lies with your webserver set-up not with PHP.

Comment: If you ignore the Foundation instruction to perform a fresh install you have to debug yourself - there are many incompatibilities